# How to get the number of arguments of `std::function`?

Tags: c++, function, c++11

Is that possible to get the number of arguments of `std::function` ? Something like `NumOfArgument<...>::value`.

For example, `NumOfArgument<function<int(int, int)> >::value` should be 2.

Comment: is there any specific reason why you want to do it in first place ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I think `std::function` itself doesn't provide that feature. But you can implement it yourself as:

```
template<typename T> 
struct count_arg;

template<typename R, typename ...Args> 
struct count_arg<std::function<R(Args...)>>
{
    static const size_t value = sizeof...(Args);
};
```

Test code:

```
typedef std::function<int(int, int)> fun;
std::cout << count_arg<fun>::value << std::endl; //should print 2
```

See this : [Online demo](http://ideone.com/mkqNE)

---

Likewise, you may put more features into this, as :

```
template<typename T> 
struct function_traits;     //renamed it!

template<typename R, typename ...Args> 
struct function_traits<std::function<R(Args...)>>
{
    static const size_t nargs = sizeof...(Args);

    typedef R result_type;

    template <size_t i>
    struct arg
    {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type type;
    };
};
```

Now you can get each argument type, using *const* index, as:

```
std::cout << typeid(function_traits<fun>::arg<0>::type).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << typeid(function_traits<fun>::arg<1>::type).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << typeid(function_traits<fun>::arg<2>::type).name() << std::endl;
```

[Working demo](http://ideone.com/pp0ow)

It prints the mangled-name of the types!

Comment: +1 : Wow it becomes really simple once you've got variadic templates working O__O;

Comment: Nice solution ... I was unaware that, `sizeof...(Args)` is a proper syntax! Does, `sizeof()` have a special meaning for `Args` ? Because generally `sizeof()` only deals with size of data type and not the number of elements.

Comment: @iammilind: `sizeof...(T)` is a special syntax to get the size of the parameter pack `T`. It has nothing to do with `sizeof(T)` (§5.3.3/5, §14.5.3/7).

Comment: One nitpick: `nargs` should really be a `size_t` for consistency with `struct arg`... and because it cannot be negative anyway.

Comment: Cool idea. I mark this as the correct answer. Thanks a lot. Anyway, I think the function_traits should be included in the standard.