# How do I get the argument types of a function pointer in a variadic template class?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, functor, variadic-templates

This is a follow up of this problem: [Generic functor for functions with any argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050047/generic-functor-for-functions-with-any-argument-list)

I have this functor class (full code see link above):

```
template<typename... ARGS>
class Foo
{
    std::function<void(ARGS...)> m_f;
public:
    Foo(std::function<void(ARGS...)> f) : m_f(f) {}
    void operator()(ARGS... args) const { m_f(args...); }
};
```

In `operator()` I can access the `args...` easily with a recursive "peeling" function as described [in Stroustrup's C++11 FAQ](//www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#variadic-templates)

My problem is: I want to access the types of the arguments of f, i.e. `ARGS...`, in the constructor. Obviously I can't access values because there are none so far, but the argument type list is somehow burried in `f`, isn't it?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can write `function_traits` class as shown below, to discover the argument types, return type, and number of arguments:

```
template<typename T> 
struct function_traits;  

template<typename R, typename ...Args> 
struct function_traits<std::function<R(Args...)>>
{
    static const size_t nargs = sizeof...(Args);

    typedef R result_type;

    template <size_t i>
    struct arg
    {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type type;
    };
};
```

Test code:

```
struct R{};
struct A{};
struct B{};

int main()
{
   typedef std::function<R(A,B)> fun;

   std::cout << std::is_same<R, function_traits<fun>::result_type>::value << std::endl;
   std::cout << std::is_same<A, function_traits<fun>::arg<0>::type>::value << std::endl;
   std::cout << std::is_same<B, function_traits<fun>::arg<1>::type>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/YeN29

Comment: Thank you @Nawaz, works so far. Nevertheless, would like to extract the "magic" out of this solution and put it into my code. I suppose typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type is where it happens... How do I do that without having to declare another struct

Comment: @steffen: Do you have any problem in defining another struct which can be used in other situations as well? Also, putting all the code in just one class is not a good idea. Try to divide code into small working units.

Comment: I get your point. One last question is this piece of code from the boost library? function_traits sounds familiar ;)

Comment: @steffen: Boost might have similar functionality. I've not seen it. Actually this solution is copied from my another answer here : [How to get the number of arguments of `std::function`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044866/how-to-get-the-number-of-arguments-of-stdfunction)

Comment: Hi again @Nawaz! It seems not to work when fun is typed std::function<void(ARGS...)> inside my variadic template constructor.

Comment: @steffen: It will work. You must be doing something wrong. Better post the code at www.ideone.com so that I can see the error myself

Comment: @steffen: The problem is that when you use `ARG...`, you need to use `typename` and `template` keywords to disambiguate the situations. So instead of `function_traits<fun_vararg>::arg<0>::type`, you need to write `typename function_traits<fun_vararg>::template arg<0>::type`. See it works now : http://ideone.com/bysFS

Comment: I posted a follow-up here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077612/using-non-const-expression-as-template-parameter

Comment: @Nawaz hm, The Wayback Machine was no help in retrieving the contents of your dead "Demo" link.  :(

Comment: Added to universal standard library.