# Get list of parameter types from function

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have banged my head during the afternoon and night trying to get a list of parameter types from a function pointer. I can get the individual parameter types with solutions like the one proposed for example here: [How do I get the argument types of a function pointer in a variadic template class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065081/how-do-i-get-the-argument-types-of-a-function-pointer-in-a-variadic-template-cla), but that breaks as I don't know how many, if any, parameters are used.

I have the following (cut down) function:

```
void LuaWrapper::Register(const char* aFunctionName, Ret(*aFunctionType(Args...))  
{
    //I can get the return value via typeid(Ret).name()
    //I would like to be able to do something like typeid(Args...).name() to get a list of all parameter types
}
```

Is what I'm asking for impossible, or am I just dense?

Comment: http://ideone.com/fig5Ib

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get one `typeid` for all `Args`, since `Args` contains multiple types.

Just get it separately for each type:

```
const char *args[] = { typeid(Args).name()... };
```