# template with std::function doesn't directly match lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

How can I best define the template function `applyFunc` to match lambda's the signature ?

I don't want to define a generic template argument capturing the function type as a whole, 
since I would like to use the type `E` of the argument of the function passed in.

```
#include <functional>
template<class E>
int applyFunc(std::function<int(E)> f) {
    return f(E{});   
}

int main()
{
    auto asLambda = [](int d) -> int {  return d+d; };
    std::function<int(int)> asFunc = asLambda;

    applyFunc(asLambda); //this doesn't :(
    applyFunc(asFunc); //this works
}
```

Compilation fails with:

```
15:23: error: no matching function for call to 'applyFunc(main()::<lambda(int)>&)'
15:23: note: candidate is:
6:5: note: template<class E> int applyFunc(std::function<int(E)>)
6:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
15:23: note:   'main()::<lambda(int)>' is not derived from 'std::function<int(E)>'
```

Comment: `applyFunc<double>([](int d) { return d+d; })`

Comment: User-defined conversions are not considered during template argument deduction. So `E` cannot be deduced unless the argument is of type `std::function<int(Something)>`; merely being convertible to such a type is not sufficient. You could always specify `E` explicitly, as @cpplearner shows.

Comment: Look at the related list... "Overloading std::function argument to match lambda", "Template argument deduction for lambdas", etc. _all_ answer your question, no?

Comment: Replace `std::function<int(E)>` with `E` and use something like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065081/how-do-i-get-the-argument-types-of-a-function-pointer-in-a-variadic-template-cla

Comment: Alternatively: `struct x { any a; x():a(){} x(any a):a(a){} template<typename T> operator T() { if(a.empty()) return {}; return any_cast<T>(a); } };` and you can use `int applyFunc(function<int(x)> f) { return f({}); }` This accepts any lambda and passes the argument correctly as long as the arguments exactly match.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb thank you for the pointing me to any. This looks a lot better ! But not quite yet ! Since I would like to have a bit more restrictions on the argument type. I will now see if i can apply this pattern you mentioned with variant.

Comment: Also I don't want explicitly mention the type as template argument. As this introduces duplication which i like to reduce.

Comment: Just by the way, `applyFunc(+asLambda);` should work.

Comment: @holyblackcat what does + does do ?

Comment: @JE42 It forces conversion to the function pointer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i tried to find this conversion in the documentation of [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) wasn't able to find it. Do you have any pointers where I can read up on this conversion ?

Comment: I'm unable to find any references on it. (It makes sense that it's not in the std::function docs, since the + is applied to a lambda, not std::function.) Maybe you should ask a new question?

Comment: Found it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889028/a-positive-lambda-what-sorcery-is-this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I best define the template function applyFunc to match lambda's the signature ?

As long as you accept to use non capturing lambdas only (as you did in the example code), you can exploit the fact that they decay to function pointers.
As a minimal, working example:

```
template<class E>
int applyFunc(int(*f)(E)) {
    return f(E{});   
}

int main() {
    auto asLambda = [](int d) -> int {  return d+d; };
    applyFunc(+asLambda);
}
```

If you want to use capturing lambdas instead, you can extract the type `E` somehow if you accept the followings:

- You must use a generic type `F` instead of a `std::function`
- You cannot use generic lambdas

Then, you can look directly at the `operator()` of your lambda.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
template<typename F>
struct GetFrom {
    template<typename R, typename E>
    static E typeE(R(F::*)(E) const);

    // required for mutable lambdas
    template<typename R, typename E>
    static E typeE(R(F::*)(E));
};

template<class F>
int applyFunc(F f) {
    using E = decltype(GetFrom<F>::typeE(&F::operator()));
    return f(E{});   
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    applyFunc([i](int d) mutable -> int {  return d+d; });
    applyFunc([i](int d) -> int {  return d+d; });
}
```

You can easily extend it to multiple arguments if you need. Use a `std::tuple` as a return type and get the i-th type from it.

Finally, if you want to use capturing lambdas and assign them to a `std::function` for whatever reason, be aware that `E` cannot be automatically deduced and thus you have to explicitly specify it (as suggested in the comments to the question by @cpplearner):

```
applyFunc<int>([](int d) { return d+d; })
```

---

**EDIT**

`GetFrom` can also be used directly in SFINAE expressions, as requested in the comments.
As a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename F>
struct GetFrom {
    template<typename R, typename E>
    static E typeE(R(F::*)(E) const);

    // required for mutable lambdas
    template<typename R, typename E>
    static E typeE(R(F::*)(E));
};

template<class F, typename E = decltype(GetFrom<F>::typeE(&F::operator()))>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<E, int>::value, E>
applyFunc(F f) {
    return f(E{});   
}

template<class F, typename E = decltype(GetFrom<F>::typeE(&F::operator()))>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<E, double>::value, E>
applyFunc(F f) {
    return f(E{});   
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    applyFunc([i](int d) mutable -> int {  return d+d; });
    applyFunc([i](double d) -> int {  return d+d; });
    // this won't compile, as expected
    // applyFunc([i](char d) -> int {  return d+d; });
}
```

Comment: can I extend GetFrom such that I can enable/disable applyFunc variant with enable_if ?

Comment: @JE42 Edited the answer. Let me know if it works for you.