# Deduction of Return / Argument types from function

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, type-deduction

I've got a hierarchy of types for Callback objects. After some heavy simplification, it looks a bit like this:

```cpp
template <typename Return, typename... Args>
struct Callback
{
  virtual Return Call(Args...) =0;

  void* mCtx;
}; // ctor, virtual dtor omitted

template <class T, typename Return, typename... Args>
struct MemberCallback: Callback<Return, Args...>
{
  Return Call(Args... args) override
  {
    return (static_cast<T*>(mCtx)->*mFn)(args...);
  }
  
  Return(T::*mFn)(Args...);
}; // ctor, specialisation for Return = void omitted

template <typename Return, typename... Args>
struct FunctionPtrCallback: Callback<Return, Args...>
{
  Return Call(Args... args) override
  {
    return mFn(args..., mCtx);
  }
  
  Return(*mFn)(Args..., void*);
}; // ctor, specialisation for Return = void omitted
```

And a factory function to deduce the type of `MemberCallback<>`s:

```cpp
template <class T, typename Return, typename... Args>
MemberCallback<T, Return, Args...> MakeCallback(T& object, Return(T::*fn)(Args...))
{
  return MemberCallback<T, Return, Args...>(&object, fn);
} // overload for const methods omitted
```

I'm trying to set up a similar factory function for `FunctionPtrCallback<>`s, however I keep running into errors:

The naive approach, `FunctionPtrCallback<Return, Args...> MakeCallback(Return(*fn)(Args..., void*), void*)` yields complaints about failing to find a suitable overload (C2672) after failing to deduce  template argument for `Return (__cdecl *)(Args...,void *)` from `void (ActualTypeUsed,void *)` (C2784).

EDITs: specifying the template arguments explicitly - `MakeCallback<void, ActualTypeUsed>` will get it to compile, *except* for functions that only take a single `void*` (`MakeCallback<void>()`).

(If I omit the `void*` argument from the signature of `fn` in the `MakeCallback` declaration, it compiles, but instantiates the wrong `FunctionPtrCallback` template - `FunctionPtrCallback<void, ActualTypeUsed, void*>` instead of `FunctionPtrCallback<void, ActualTypeUsed>`.)

I have then tried to use an interim 'function traits' template, akin to the one suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9065203/79344 :

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct FnTraits;

template <typename Return, typename... Args>
struct FnTraits<Return(Args...)>
{
  FunctionPtrCallback<Return, Args...> MakeCallback(Return(*fn)(Args..., void*), void* data)
  {
    return FunctionPtrCallback<Return, Args...>(fn, data);
  }
};
```

The complaint is now about using an incomplete type in nested name specifier for my `FnTraits<decltype(MyCallback)>::MakeCallback(MyCallback, myData)`. Placing the declaration of `MyCallback` before `FnTraits<>` (however impractical), doesn't help either.

1, In neat, academical terms, why is my approach wrong / what am I misunderstanding about template deduction?

2, If there is a way to make it work, getting `Return` and `Args...` from my callbacks auto-deduced, what is it?

(I'm aware of `std::function<>`; I'd prefer to avoid using it.)

EDIT: [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/3b1xb7)

Comment: Can you provide a [mre], perhaps a godbolt.org link?

Comment: @jtbandes added one now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems like a pack expansion where the pack is not at the end of the list, such as `Return(*)(Args..., void*)`, is a **non-deduced context** (see [#8 here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts); disclaimer: I'm not a language lawyer). This means that `Args` cannot be deduced from the type of `FooBaz` in your example.

However, you can work around this by making it so the parameter pack is deduced to **include** the `void*`, and then removing the `void*` later: https://godbolt.org/z/aTTqbc

```cpp
// Given Args that doesn't include void*, take the parameter pack
// out of the tuple and put it into the desired FunctionPtrCallback type.
template <typename Return, typename Tuple>
struct MakeCallbackImpl;
template <typename Return, typename... Args>
struct MakeCallbackImpl<Return, std::tuple<Args...>> {
    using type = FunctionPtrCallback<Return, Args...>;
};

// Given Args that *does* include void*, remove it using RemoveLast.
// Args can now be deduced because it appears last in Return(*)(Args...).
template <typename Return, typename... Args>
auto MakeCallback(Return(*fn)(Args...), void* data) {
    return typename MakeCallbackImpl<Return, typename RemoveLast<Args...>::type>::type(fn, data);
}
```

And the helper `RemoveLast`, inspired by [this forum thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/115447/#msg630296) (but using `std::tuple_cat` as a convenience instead of defining a custom concat):

```cpp
template<typename First, typename... Rest>
struct RemoveLast {
    using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(
        std::declval<std::tuple<First>>(),
        std::declval<typename RemoveLast<Rest...>::type>()
    ));
};

template<typename First>
struct RemoveLast<First> {
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};
```

Comment: It works great! Thank you for your help. (Took a while to get around to trying it out -- sorry.)