# Can I get a parameter pack from an (old-style) function signature?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I want to declare a method - variadic - where its signature comes from an "old-style" function signature as template parameter.

You can declare, say, a `std::function` using a function signature, e.g.,

```
std::function<int(float,float)> f;
```

Now I'd like to have a template which takes a function signature like that and declares a method somehow:

```
template <typename F>
struct Foo {
   [F's-return-type] Method(F's-Arg-pack]...) { ... }
};
```

So if you instantiate it as follows you get a method as follows:

```
   Foo<int(float,float)> foo;
   int x = foo.Method(1.0f, 2.0f);
```

Or maybe there's a different way to do this?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065081/how-do-i-get-the-argument-types-of-a-function-pointer-in-a-variadic-template-cla

Answer (score 7):

You can disassemble `F` using a pretty straightforward partial specialization:

```cpp
template <class F>
struct Foo;

template <class Ret, class... Params>
struct Foo<Ret(Params...)> {
    Ret Method(Params...) { /* ... */ }
};
```

[See it live on Coliru](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NXIDWhDC6TrWWgQj)

Comment: Didn't even occur to me to partially-specialize in that way.  Partial-specialization is pretty flexible!  (Will choose an answer to green-check later ...)

Answer (score 1):

But of course! Result type is easy, this is simply `std::function::result_type`. Extracting argument type is less straightforward, and requires partial class specialization (at least, in my solution):

```
template<class F> struct Foo;
template<class R, class... Args>
struct Foo<std::function<R(Args...)>
{
   R Method(Args... args) { ... }
};
```

Comment: Didn't even occur to me to partially-specialize in that way.  Partial-specialization is pretty flexible!  (Will choose an answer to green-check later ...)

Answer (score 0):

You need partial specializations, one for each kind of functions.
hopefully for regular functions (so not the [abominable functions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html)), there are less:

```
template <class Sig>
struct Foo;

template <typename Ret, typename... Ts>
struct Foo<Ret(Ts...)> {
    Ret Method(Ts...) const { /* .. */ }
};

// C-ellipsis (printf-like)
template <typename Ret, typename... Ts>
struct Foo<Ret(Ts..., ...)> {
    Ret Method(Ts..., ...) const { /* .. va_arg and co */ }
};
```

For methods, the combination is bigger (cv-qualifier (x4), ref-qualifier (x3), so 24).