# how to create static member function from class template typedef argument?

Tags: c++, templates, static-methods, template-meta-programming, c++-concepts

I'm trying to build a class template where one static methodneeds to have the typedef specified in the template argument.
The goal is to specify a typedef like this `typedef foobar = void __stdcall foo(int a, float b)` and pass that to my template `Foo<foobar>();`. From that the class Foo should have a static member function with the exact typedef `void __stdcall foo(int a, float b)`

My initial draft for this template class looks like this:

```
template<class T, class ... Args>
class Foo
{
    static T Bar(Args... args);
};
```

Where `Bar` is the static method created from the template.

This does not account for calling conventions, implicit this pointers etc... however I was able to create a function with the correct return type and arguments. Is it possible to create a function from a typedef?

Comment: `typedef foobar = void foo(int a, float b);` is invalid. Replace `typedef` with `using`.

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: A function return type can never be a function type in c++. So this isn't possible. Make the return type to be something else like a pointer.

Comment: Don't change the question after there are already answer to your original question. Instead should ask a new separate question.

Comment: You’re precisely right. I meant to say using. 

I wouldn’t say it’s an XY problem. The goal is nothing more than building a static member function from a typedef

Comment: @Jon It is possible to create a static member function from a typedef but the typedef must not be a function type. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77331705/12002570)

Comment: The stackoverflow help center said to update questions to improve them. I’m sorry if that was a mistake

Comment: do you want `Bar` to have the same signature as some other function or do you want `Bar` to return that other function? I first understood the first, but then I found you say you want `Foo<foobar>` which means the latter.

Comment: @Jon See [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PzPP66ssx) where I've removed the errors. Also from your question, it seems you want the return type of the static member function to be the typedef.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai exactly, the latter. I’m sorry if the phrasing of the question or the variable names were ambigious.

Comment: @user12002570 The static member should  have the identical function signature. ”From that the class Foo should have a static member function with the exact typedef void __stdcall foo(int a, float b)” sorry if this was unclear. I’ll try and rephrase it

Comment: No worries. I totally agree that it is not kind to alter the question into asking something else after you received an answer. You can open a new question. And even if you think it is not a XY question, it helps if you explain what you need this for. An example of how you intend to use the static function eg would have avoided this misunderstanding

Comment: i see this possible using [function traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065081/how-do-i-get-the-argument-types-of-a-function-pointer-in-a-variadic-template-cla) ,  i just can't come up with the code at this moment.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai you’re probably right. I’ll make a more detailed post including an example of how this is intended to be used. My understanding was that I was meant to try and keep stackoverflow questions short and straight to the point. I seem to be banned from asking questions, but I’ll make a better post if that ban is ever lifted

Comment: @Jon So you want your static method to have the signature `void (int, int)` or `void (T...)` ?

Comment: I used T to try and capture the return type from the signature. I think my template was wrong.

if a signature like `void(*)(int, int)` is passed in I want Bar to have the signature `static void Bar(int a, int b);`  -- so exactly what you said.

If the function signatue passed in is different, like `int(*)(float)` I want Bar too look like `static int Bar(float x)`

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a function from a typedef?

Yes but the syntax `typedef foobar = void __stdcall foo(int a, float b)` isn't correct. The correct syntax would be as shown below:

```
// note the use of "using" and also that "foo" is removed from here
using foobar = void __stdcall (int a, float b)
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PzPP66ssx)

---

Now coming to the more important issue, the return type of a function can never be a *function type* so even though we were able to typedef a function type, it cannot be used as a return type of the static function.

Note that if the typedef were something other than *function type*, then you could have used it as the return type of the static member function as shown below:

```
template<class T, class ... Args>
class Foo
{
    static T Bar(Args... args);
};

using foobar = void (*)(int a, float b); //pointer to function
int main()
{
    Foo<foobar> f;
}
```

Comment: I see. The ultimate goal would obviously be to somehow extract the return type of the typedef and use that as the return type.

Comment: @Jon I can update the answer. Do you want your static method to have the signature `void (int, int)` or `void (T...)`? That is, you basically want to extract the return type `void` from the typedef?

Comment: void(int, int) would be correct if what was passed in was a function signature with return type void and two parameters of type int.

`using signature = void(*)(int a, float b); //function signature`

when passed to Foo, `Foo<signature>`, Bar looks like this
`static void Bar(int a, float b);`

```using signature2 = int(*)(float x);
Foo<signature2>
static int Bar(float x);
```
I hope this makes sense :)