# How to grab the argument and return types from a std::function with cv and reference qualifiers?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Is there a good way to grab the argument and return types from a `std::function` such that we also return the cv and reference qualifiers?  This partially relates to a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044866/how-to-get-the-number-of-arguments-of-stdfunction).  In any case, using the code in the answer, we have the following example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> 
struct function_traits;

template<typename R, typename ...Args> 
struct function_traits<std::function<R(Args...)>> {
    static const size_t nargs = sizeof...(Args);

    typedef R result_type;

    template <size_t i>
    struct arg {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type
            type;
    };
};

template <typename T>
void foo(T const & f) {
    typedef function_traits <T> stuff;
    std::cout <<
        typeid(typename function_traits <T>::result_type).name()
        << std::endl;
    std::cout <<
        typeid(typename function_traits <T>::template arg<0>::type).name()
        << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Function: f" << std::endl;
    auto f = [](double x) { return x+1.;};
    foo <std::function<double(double)>> (f);

    std::cout << std::endl << "Function: g" << std::endl;
    auto g = [](double const & x) { return x+1.;};
    foo <std::function<double(double const &)>> (g);
}
```

Now, using c++filt, we see the type of `f` is `std::function<double (double)>` and the type of `g` is `std::function<double (double const&)>`.  However, the structure `function_traits` reports the argument types to be the same, which they are not.  Basically, the `const&` was stripped off the argument type for `g`.  Is there a way to fix this so that `const&` is retained?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `const` and reference are stripped off by `typeid`, not by `function_traits`.  Try adding

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<double,
    typename function_traits<T>::template arg<0>::type>::value  << std::endl;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<const double&,
    typename function_traits<T>::template arg<0>::type>::value << std::endl;
```

to your `foo` and you'll see the expected values.

Comment: Thanks!  By the way, is there a way to print out the cv qualifier without using is_same?  Basically, a version of `typeid` that keeps all the qualifiers.

Comment: One quick way is to `typeid(wrap<T>)` and just ignore the `wrap` part in the output.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Unless I'm missing something and in case anyone else is trying this, this trick requires the definition, `template <typename T>
struct wrap{};`.  Then, we see something like: `wrap<double const&>` out of c++filt.